# Create Materialized view which refresh records on daily

Tags: oracle, view, refresh, materialized-views

Currently the Materialized view which I had created using REFRESH ON DEMAND so in this case I need to refresh MV explicitly using below command:

```
BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MV_DATA'); END;
```

But now I need to refresh this MV on daily basis so could anyone please help to write this. I have seen that we can refresh this MV using writing explicit Job or using COMPLETE/FAST REFRESH statement in MV itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So if you have seen the ways MV can be refreshed, what is your exact problem?

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin: I need to do this automate refresh instead of doing this manually

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to create the materialized view using START WITH and NEXT Clause

```
create materialized view <mview_name>
refresh on demand 
start with sysdate next sysdate + 1
as select ............
```

So if you want to refresh mview daily, you need to keep it refresh on demand and set the next refresh time as `sysdate + 1`. You can set any interval although.

Once you do this the materialized view is created and  a job is set in Oracle that will refresh mview every 24 hrs `(sysdate + 1)`.

For more information on how to do that, follow [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html#GUID-EE262CA4-01E5-4618-B659-6165D993CA1B)

Comment: if it is scheduled to be refreshed automatically then why on demand ?

Comment: `On Demand` is default mode and scheduled refresh(automatic) is also part of `on demand` mode. Apart from that you can mention `on commit` where mview will be refreshed when DML happens on underlying tables and commit is fired.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply need a SQL query to simply refresh at `12 AM`, then the below query would be enough.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DATA
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST START WITH (SYSDATE) NEXT (SYSDATE + 1) WITH ROWID
ON COMMIT
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS SELECT * FROM <YOUR TABLE>
```

If you need to have it refreshed around `6 AM`, then use the below script. You can see and additional logic as `+ 6 / 24`. In case if you need to change to `4 AM`, use the logic as `+ 4 / 24`.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DATA
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST START WITH (SYSDATE) NEXT (SYSDATE + 1) + 6 / 24 WITH ROWID
ON COMMIT
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS SELECT * FROM <YOUR TABLE>
```

Comment: IMMEDIATE not IMMEDEATE

Comment: How would you do 7:30?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited Sarath's Script for it to run on specific time (i.e. 6AM).

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_DATA
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST START WITH (SYSDATE) NEXT (TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1) + 6 / 24 WITH ROWID
ON COMMIT
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE
```

Answer (score -1):

Refresh the mv every day at 1 AM

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test1 
  BUILD IMMEDIATE
  USING INDEX 
  REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND START WITH sysdate+0 NEXT (trunc(sysdate)+1)+1/24
  USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT
  USING ENFORCED CONSTRAINTS DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
  "Your query"