# Create Materialized View With Defined Columns & Refresh Rate

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, oracle, migration, materialized-views

I am having an issue with the exact syntax of:

- creating a materialize view
- setting a refresh time
- disabling query rewrite

I am trying to do that all of that during the create.
This query will be executed via rails migration, I am trying to get it right outside of rails first.

In sql developer I am getting an error in the IDE

`Syntax error partially recognized rules (railroad diagrams): unusable_editions_clause := UNUSABLE`

The syntax error is located at  `("C`  of `REWRITE ("COLUMN1",`

The error I get on a rails migration is

`OCIError: ORA-00905: missing keyword: CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "MT_VIEW"...`

Query:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "MT_VIEW"
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST START WITH (SYSDATE) NEXT (SYSDATE + 1) + 5 / 24 WITH ROWID
ON COMMIT
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE ("COLUMN1",
              "COLUMN2")  AS...
```

I built this portion of the query based on: [Create Materialized view which refresh records on daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481099/create-materialized-view-which-refresh-records-on-daily/22482331)

His example doesn't have column names on the view, I've tried putting the `BUILD..` after the column names but that throws different error. This [says](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:852227225161) `BUILD` should be at the top.

UPDATE:

Here is what I ended up with (based on the answer):

```
BEGIN
   dbms_refresh.make(
    name                        =>       'refresh',
    list                        =>       'mt_view',
    next_date                   =>       SYSDATE + 1,
    interval                    =>       'next_day(trunc(sysdate), ''SATURDAY'') + 4/24',
    implicit_destroy            =>       FALSE,
    lax                          =>      TRUE
  );
END;
```

Key things:

- `name` cannot start with a number
- `list` cannot be empty
- you need an interval
- `next_date` doesn't need to be a string, string didn't work for me

Good resources for this:

- https://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/pkgs/dbms_refresh.html#refr7
- https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/10893_2200191_2/Manually-Refreshing-Materialized-Views-and-Creating-Refresh-Groups-in-Oracle.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW you do not specify column names separately from the query, as you would with a normal view. Column names are only/always derived from the query itself, though you can use aliases there. See here for examples and syntax:

- https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html#GUID-EE262CA4-01E5-4618-B659-6165D993CA1B

Also:

- In general, don't use quotation marks on object names or column names, as it forces case-sensitivity which would not exist otherwise. It is generally considered bad practice in Oracle, as you will then be forced to use quotation marks every time you reference that object in the future.
- If your intent is to have your MV refresh at 5:00am every day, your NEXT clause will not accomplish that. Currently it will run 29 hours from the time the job finishes, which is an odd schedule and (as with most DBMS_JOB schedules) will have a start time that creeps by the amount of time it takes to run the job, every time. If you want precise timing of your refresh and built in logging of the job execution, it is recommended to use Oracle Scheduler rather than the default DBMS_JOB. That will require additional DDL commands (can't do it in the CREATE MV). If you are using Oracle 19c or later, Oracle Scheduler is used by default, but you must still be careful with how you specify your start/next times if you put them in the CREATE MV statement.
- You can't have ON COMMIT *and* scheduled execution with START/NEXT. You need to pick one or the other.

So use something like this to get everything in one command:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MT_VIEW
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST
ON DEMAND START WITH (SYSDATE) NEXT TRUNC(SYSDATE+1)+5/24 WITH ROWID
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE 
AS SELECT ...
```

Or do this and then create an Oracle Scheduler job to execute the MV refresh and log the results on a fixed schedule.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MT_VIEW
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST
ON DEMAND WITH ROWID
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE 
AS SELECT ...

begin
   dbms_refresh.make(
     name                 => '5AM_REFRESH',
     list                 => '',
     next_date            => '/* 5am */ trunc(sysdate+1)+5/24',
     interval             => null,
     implicit_destroy     => false,
     lax                  => false,
     job                  => 0,
     rollback_seg         => null,
     push_deferred_rpc    => true,
     refresh_after_errors => true,
     purge_option         => null,
     parallelism          => null,
     heap_size            => null);
end;
/

begin
   dbms_refresh.add(
     name => '5AM_REFRESH',
     list => 'MT_VIEW',
     lax  => true);
end;
/

commit;
```

Comment: For the make of `dbms_refresh.make` I got an error.

Comment: Error report -
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at line 2
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

Comment: Try removing the "/* 5am */" comment in the next_date.